# Angular Radio Buttons Instead of Select

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to replace a select with radio buttons - but when I swap to radio buttons I loose my initial selection and the selecting breaks.

```
$scope.selection = Address.get(); // { id: 1, name: "Home" };
$scope.addresses = Address.query(); // [{ id: 1, name: "Home" }, { id: 2, name: "Work" }];
```

From (in this sample the select has "Home" selected):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selection" 
  ng-options="address.street for address in addresses track by address.id">
</select>
```

To (in this sample the radio button for "Home" is not selected):

```
<div ng-repeat="address in addresses track by address.id">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-value="address" ng-model="selection" />
    <span>{{address.name}}</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xczdcqx0/7/

**EDIT**:

I need the `selection` to reflect the `id` and `name` after changes:

```
<span>Selection:</span> <span>{{selection.name}} - {{selection.id}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Source:**

```
<div ng-repeat="address in addresses track by address.id">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-checked="checked(address)" ng-click="click(address)" />
    <span>{{address.name}}</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**Controller**:

```
app.controller("SampleController", ["$scope", "Address", function($scope, Address) {
  $scope.selection = Address.get(); // { id: 1, name: "Home" };
  $scope.addresses = Address.query(); // [{ id: 1, name: "Home" }, { id: 2, name: "Work" }];

  $scope.checked = function(address) {  
    return address.id === $scope.selection.id; 
  };

  $scope.click = function(address) {
    $scope.selection = address;
  };
}]);
```

Note: extracted partially from solutions provided by @bri.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (for you radio input).  Turns out that the ng-repeat is what's throwing it off (you needed to use $parent.selection):

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="address" ng-model="$parent.selection"/>
```

I think it's working the way you'd hope with [this update to your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psberxyu/)

**Initial Value**

Jeez.  *I feel like an idiot*, but I finally figured out that angular has no way of telling that your initial "selection" is the same as address[0].

So - I had to change the way you set $scope.selection as well:

```
app.controller("SampleController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.addresses = [
    { id: 1, name: "Home" }, 
    { id: 2, name: "Work" },
   ];
  $scope.selection = $scope.addresses[0];
}]);
```

Now we're all set.  Sheesh ... that was one of those "hiding in plain sight" bugs...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but doing this seems to first change the `id` of the selected address (clicking a few times between options breaks things).

Comment: This is closer... you need to reference $parent.selection (since the radio is inside an ng-repeat).

Comment: Ah, yeah I see that now the changes work - just getting the initial selection.

Comment: Finally.  Sorry ... that last bit was just me being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The value and model should be a string according to the [input[radio]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) docs:

```
  <input type="radio" ng-value="address.name" ng-model="selection.name" />
```

**JSFiddle Demo: **https://jsfiddle.net/xczdcqx0/2/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a bit of a simplification but I'd also like to keep `selection.id` updated. I'll updated my question to reflect this.